# Is there a way to prove to a third party that you are the recipient of a transaction?

Tags: contract-development, transactions, contract-design, history, receipts

Let's say that someone sends me some ETH. How can I prove to a third party that I am the actual recipient of that transaction?
The third party is anyone with access to the blockchain. In other words, I want to send some data to this third party that allows it to verify that I am the recipient of a specific transaction on the blockchain.

Comment: This question needs a lot more detail. Who needs to prove? What is the proof method? (ie. address, hash, etc.) Is the third-party a contract?

Comment: @ReyHaynes added details

Comment: Why can't you just send a transaction from the same address which received the original transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [sign](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-util/blob/master/docs/index.md#ecsign) a message hash using the private key of the account that received the transaction. [ecrecover](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-util/blob/master/docs/index.md#ecrecover) can be used to verify the signature was generated from that account.